# Least squares estimator for AR(1)

Tags: time-series, self-study, least-squares

There is one task, which was assigned to me by my professor:

Assume that $X_1, ..., X_n$ is a sample from $AR(1)$ model, i.e. $X_t - \phi X_{t-1} = \mu + Z_t,$ where $Z_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$, parameters $\mu$ and $\phi$ are unknown. Find the least squares estimator of $(\mu, \phi)$.

In order to solve this problem I was trying to solve this systems of two equations that are obtained by considering partial derivatives with respect to $\phi$ and $\mu$:

\begin{cases}
\sum_{t=1}^n(X_t - \mu - \phi X_{t-1}) = 0 \\
\sum_{t=1}^n(X_t - \mu - \phi X_{t-1})X_{t-1} = 0
\end{cases}

I was trying to rewrite these two equations and obtain $\mu$ and $\phi$ values but after getting that $\mu = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^nX_t -\phi X_{t-1}}{n}$ I stopped. Maybe somebody has some ideas how I could solve this system more easily because now I am trying to plug in $\mu$ into the second equation and group different $X_t$'s.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path! You can make the calculations more manageable by introducing some notation here.

Let me start with a small comment, that may or may not make sense yet: You can think of the defining equation
$$ X_t = \phi \, X_{t-1} + \mu + Z_t$$
as simply the formula for a plain old *[simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)* of the series $X_{t}$ as a function of $X_{t-1}$. That means, to get the least square estimators or $\mu, \phi$, all you have to do is remember them for linear regression!

Ok, let's get into actually calculating this:

As you've found out yourself, the sum of least squares that you're trying to minimise is
$$ E =  \frac{1}{2\,n}\sum_{t=2}^n (X_t - \phi \, X_{t-1} - \mu )^2$$
so the partial derivatives are
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial \mu} =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=2}^n (\phi \, X_{t-1} + \mu - X_t)$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial \phi} =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=2}^n (\phi \, X_{t-1} + \mu - X_t) \, X_{t-1}$$
Now, have a look at the terms in those sums... these are just sample averages and higher moments. Indeed
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial \mu} =   \phi \, \langle X_{t-1} \rangle + \mu - \langle X_t \rangle$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial \phi} =  \phi \, \langle X_{t-1} ^2 \rangle + \mu \langle X_{t-1} \rangle - \langle X_t \, X_{t-1} \rangle$$
where I've just switched notation $\langle ... \rangle \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_t ...$ to clean things up a bit.

Now we can solve that coupled linear system of equations using linear algebra. First write it as a matrix equation
$$  \left( \begin{matrix}
1 & \langle X_{t-1} \rangle \\
\langle X_{t-1} \rangle & \langle X_{t-1} ^2 \rangle  
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
\mu \\
\phi
\end{matrix} \right)  = \left( \begin{matrix}
\langle X_{t} \rangle \\
\langle  X_{t-1} \ X_{t} \rangle
\end{matrix} \right) ~ . $$

Inverting the matrix gives
$$   \left( \begin{matrix}
\mu \\
\phi
\end{matrix} \right)  = \frac{1}{var(X_{t-1})} \left( \begin{matrix}
cov( X_{t} X_{t-1}  , X_{t-1} ) - cov( X_{t} , X_{t-1}^2 )\\
cov( X_{t-1} , \ X_{t} )
\end{matrix} \right) ~ . $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!